# query joining three tables yii

Tags: php, mysql, yii

How to convert  mysql query to yii.?

I have 3 table

1. user_header
2. customers
3. customer_ratings

and this is my sql query

```
SELECT t.email 
FROM   otz_user_header t 
       JOIN otz_customers r 
         ON t.user_id = r.customer_user_id 
       JOIN otz_customer_ratings cr 
         ON cr.customer_user_id = r.customer_user_id 
WHERE  r.rate_auto_approve = 0 
       AND r.rate_email_time IS NOT NULL 
       AND r.total_rating_count IS NOT NULL 
       AND cr.rating_date < Curdate() 
       AND cr.rating_date > Date_sub(Curdate(), INTERVAL 7 day)
```

How to convert  this query to yii ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can run mysql statements directly in Yii. But if you would like to use the active record approach, you can consult Yii's doc on [relational active records](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/database.arr).

Comment: One issue i don't understand. For complex queries with multiple joins, active record is slower than DAO in any benchmark. Even yiis guide mentions it. As far i did long ago, i always found it a second slower. But still people opt for active record.... Am i missing something here? Even query builder is faster than AR.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

"itachi"  answer's right, but if you are looking for in activerecord way...

model: **UserHeader**

relations:

```
'activeCustomers' => array(
     self::HAS_MANY, 
     'Customer', 
     'customer_user_id', 
     'condition' => 'activeCustomers.rate_auto_approve=0 
                  AND activeCustomers.rate_email_time IS NOT NULL 
                  AND activeCustomers.total_rating_count IS NOT NULL'
),
```

model: **Customer**

relations:

```
'lastWeekRatings' => array(
     self::HAS_MANY, 
     'CustomerRating', 
     'customer_user_id', 
     'condition' => 'lastWeekRatings.rating_date < CURDATE() 
        AND lastWeekRatings.rating_date > DATE_SUB( CURDATE(), INTERVAL 7 DAY )'
),
```

and the below code returns the MODEL objects as same as your query. ( I haven't tested it )

```
$useremails = UserHeader::model()
     ->with('activeCustomers', 'activeCustomers.lastWeekRatings')
     ->findAll(array(
           'select' => 't.email'
      ));
print_r($useremails);
```

Comment: How to we access those data using foreach statement?

Comment: @ElsonSolano,  findAll() always return an array(or arrayaccess object). you can loop through foreach ($useremails as $userHeader)  and you can access fields as '$userHeader->email' and the relations '$userHeader->activeCustomers' this is list of Customer records  and '$userHeader->activeCustomers->lastWeekRatings' this is list of CustomerRating objects.

Answer (score 5):

**USE DAO (*data access object*)**

**MODEL**

---

```
public function test(){
        $sql = "SELECT t.email
            FROM otz_user_header t
            JOIN otz_customers r ON t.user_id = r.customer_user_id
            JOIN otz_customer_ratings cr ON cr.customer_user_id = r.customer_user_id
            WHERE r.rate_auto_approve =0
            AND r.rate_email_time IS NOT NULL
            AND r.total_rating_count IS NOT NULL
            AND cr.rating_date < CURDATE( )
            AND cr.rating_date >DATE_SUB( CURDATE( ) , INTERVAL 7
            DAY )";

        return Yii::app()->db->createCommand($sql)->queryAll();
            }
```